# How do i edit my Arch system to display custom message on each tty?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, getty

I use Arch linux with i3 and xfce4 desktop environment. I have configured **tty1** to open **i3-gaps** and **tty2** to open **xfce4**. Is there a way to display a custom message on each **tty** saying that the current tty will open i3 window manager etc. I know about the `/etc/issue` file to show a message, but i would like to  have a separate message for each tty **before login**. Is this possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the contents of `/etc/issue2` when opening tty2, run `systemctl edit getty@tty2`, and paste the following contents:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --issue-file /etc/issue2 -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear %I $TERM
```

This modifies `getty@.service`, but only for tty2. See `systemctl cat getty@` for the un-modified service file.

With this drop-in snippet, the first `ExecStart=` line means "discard any `ExecStart` line that was present in the original service file", and the second `ExecStart=` line is the one I found in `systemctl cat getty@`, but I've added `--issue-file /etc/issue2` so tty2 will use a different issue file than the other ttys.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the banner displayed after the login changing the content of the file `/etc/motd`.

Comment: Sorry but i need to show a message before login. Is there a way to edit system files? The `/etc/issue` file lets me show a message but its the same for each **tty** . I would like a custom message for each **tty**